# Sci-Fi story about a detective uncovering a conspiracy, getting captured and tortured

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I only read the last part of the story in a magazine that used to publish short stories like this in chapters.

The final chapter of this one went like this: The protagonist is driving to his boss to tell him about what he has discovered about the plans of Some corporations that would seriously damage The planet and its environment. Then he finds out he's being followed by multiple cars. He tries to contact his boss and ask for help, but his signal's being jammed. He's finally captured and taken somewhere, where he's bound and tortured using a device that sends pain signals directly to the brain, leaving him temporarily blind. Then he hears a stranger come in, talk to the people torturing him, and finally killing them all and setting him free. When he asks the stranger about their identity, They introduce themself as "The spirit of the planet X" where X is the name of the planet the story takes place on. At the end of the story, our protagonist is talking to his boss about the whole thing and when he tells him about the stranger and what they said their name was, his boss says "You don't believe in that kind of superstition, do you?"

Comment: About how long ago did you read it? Do you remember the names of any of the magazines you were reading at the time?

Comment: That wouldn't be helpful. I read it around 2000 in an Iranian magazine called "ettelaat-e-elmi", so the story was translated to Persian. I have also checked the archive of said magazine, but couldn't find it.